# DAX measures cannot find all tables

Tags: dax, powerpivot, measure

I’m writing my first DAX measure. When selecting the table , I cannot find all my tables ? Is there any reason why ? (Transaction table not found)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean that when you write dax measure you cannot select columns from some tables. Most likely this is because there's no relationship between the tables. E.g. If I try to divide column A from Table A by column B from Table B, it will not allow me to do that (column B will not be auto-suggested), because it doesn't know how table A relates to table B.

Answer (score 0):

When you write a measure your not working in the context of a particular table or row, so you will only be able to reference *other measures* or columns on tables inside an aggregate function, like SUM.

So Intellisense in the measure definition will only find a table if it has a measure attached to it.

If you type

`MyMeasure = Sum(`

then you should see suggestions for all the tables in your model.